# Disable send update to all attendees VSTO

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, appointment

I'm using VSTO to develop add-in for Outlook.

When using `Send` method of `MeetingItem` (`AppointmentItem`), how can I disable Send Update to All Attendees popup? It always show when I call `Send` of existing meeting.

I only found `ForceUpdateToAllAttendees` property but it make the update send to all attendees, that would be wrong if user don't want to send updates to all attendees.

EDIT:

This is my code

```
void Application_ItemSend(object item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    var form = new SC01(item);
    form.Show();
    Cancel = true; // prevent mail sending
}
```

...
in SC01 form:

```
private void btn_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var meetingItem = _item As MeetingItem;    // _item is private field of SC01
    meetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(false).Send(); // this Send() will make sending option (to update attendees only or to all attendees
}
```

Comment: if the user shll be able to decide if the update is sent to everyone, then why don't you like the popup?

Comment: Actually, when user click on Send button, then choose sending option, a confirmation popup will appear. If user click OK on this popup, `Send()` function will be called to actually send the item. At this time, the sending option popup appear again, that not I want.

Comment: How is the confirmation pop-up called? And is your send-button calling the send-procedure already or something else?

Comment: When user click on Outlook Send button, it will enter `ItemSend` event of application (send procedure already called), I set `Cancel = true` for not sending the mail, then display popup form. And in my popup, when user click OK, `meetingItem.Send()` method will be called.

Comment: please post your code, I think I have a solution, whuich is easier to explain with your code.

Comment: @Max, I updated my post with code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I was away some days.  I think I have the solution, althuogh I only "speak" vba - but in the end it is all the same...

leave away the line:

```
Cancel = true; // prevent mail sending
```

and also the line:

```
meetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(false).Send();
```

as far as I know the item will not be sent anyway as long as the form is not hidden again.

I hope this works!
Max

Comment: Yes I know, if the form is `ShowDialog`, it will prevent mail sending. But my form is using `Show` instead...

Comment: maybe it would be helpful to know what you are aiming to do in the end. why does it have to be "Show" and not "showdialog"

Answer (score 0):

just had another idea that should solve your Problem:

```
void Application_ItemSend(object item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    var form = new SC01(item);
    form.Show();
   '''next line is new and prevents the first popup
      item.ForceUpdateToAllAttendees = TRUE
    Cancel = true; // prevent mail sending
}
```

... in SC01 form:

```
private void btn_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var meetingItem = _item As MeetingItem;    // _item is private field of SC01
   '''next line is new => popup Comes now
      meetingItem.ForceUpdateToAllAttendees = FALSE
    meetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(false).Send(); // this Send() will make sending option (to update attendees only or to all attendees
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was too busy to check your answer. I've tried but if `ForceUpdateToAllAttendees` is `false` before `Send()`, the popup appears. Only if `ForceUpdateToAllAttendees` is `true`, the popup will not show.